# JQuery with AJAX can't get content from php page

Tags: javascript, php

**JQuery with AJAX can't get content from php page**

I try press the submit button, nothing change. Not sure why

Heres my 2 pages

**Jquery.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#input").click(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: 'jquery2.php?keyword='+$("#fname").val(),
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {$("#newhtml").val(data);}
});

    })


    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
<input type="button" id="input" value="Search Data">
<div id="newhtml"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery2.php**

```
<?php
    $advert = array(
        'ajax' => 'Hello world!',
        'advert' => $row['adverts'],
     );
    echo json_encode($advert);
?>
```

Is there anythign wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$("#newhtml").val(data);
```

should be

```
$("#newhtml").html(data);
// OR
$("#newhtml").append(data);
```

You might also have to add

```
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json"
```

properties to your *ajax* method before *success* callback.

**UPDATE**

Overall, your code in your head tag should be like this

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#input").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'jquery2.php?keyword='+$("#fname").val(),
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function (data) {
            $("#newhtml").html(data);
          }
        });
    });
 });

</script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
success: function (data) {$("#newhtml").val(data);}
```

to

```
success: function (data) {$("#newhtml").html(data);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use multiple jquery sources.
Use only one among those two you referenced.

For non INPUT tags u have to use .html() or .text()

Answer (score 0):

Jquery2.php throws an error:
"Notice:  Undefined variable: **row** in [...]/Jquery2.php on line 4"

**$row['adverts']** is not defined.

Also, change following:

```
$("#newhtml").val(data);
```

to

```
$("#newhtml").html(data);
```